# Mandelbrot Boundary Area

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I might be entirely off an my assumptions, but the following has led me to a question.

1. The Mandelbrot set is contained by an border of infinite length.
2. Said border is 2-dimensional.
3. The Hilbert space-filling curve also is 2-dimensional and infinite in length.
4. The Hilbert curve covers an area of 1 square unit.

Can the Mandelbrot border be assigned an area?  Am I justified in saying that the Hilbert curve is has area 1?  If it is two dimensional, that seems reasonable.  What terminology is used for non-integer dimensions?  Also, for integer dimensions.  What do you call the measure of the 4D interior of a tesseract?  5D?

I'm in 10th grade, but very good at math (taking Calc BC), so as long as answers don't go to deep into metric spaces, measure theory, topology, et cetera, I should be able to follow them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37229/area-of-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594562/the-mandelbrot-set-has-a-well-defined-area-its-boundary-has-hausdorff-dimension